# Replicate row on specific date condition pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, date, pyspark

So i have a dataset like this:

```
| DATE      | Value    |
| 2022-10-01| x        |
| 2022-11-01| y        |
| 2021-12-01| z        |
| 2022-01-01| xy       |
```

I prepared code to list out the difference between max date in this dataset and current date (2023-01-01). As there is no such date as 2022-12-01 or 2023-01-01 in my dataset, now i want to replicate the same row with the same values BUT from the year before AND set the year for the correct date. So the output should look like this:

```
| DATE      | Value    |
| 2023-01-01| xy       |
| 2022-12-01| z        |
| 2022-10-01| x        |
| 2022-11-01| y        |
| 2021-12-01| z        |
| 2022-01-01| xy       |
```

The code that i wrote to list out the missing data:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

max_dt = max(shares_union.select("Date").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())
max_dt

diff_months = relativedelta(datetime.now(), max_dt).months
diff_months

for m in range(1, diff_months+1):
    print((max_dt + relativedelta(months=m)).replace(day=1))
    print()
```

output:

```
2022-12-01

2023-01-01
```

THX for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this type of problem might be hard to express in native PySpark. I will use the [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/) library, which allows us to express our logic in terms of Python and Pandas. When the solution is ready, we can easily switch the execution engine to Spark.

We'll first work through the logic with only Pandas/Python and worry about bringing it to Spark later. This should make it more readable and maintainable.

First the setup:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"DATE": ["2022-10-01", "2022-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01"],
                   "Value": ["x", "y", "z", "xy"]})
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
```

This problem might be easier if we perform the operation by month. Anyway, each timestamp only cares about the month of the previous year if I understand right. So we can make a function to get us the month and year. Again, it will be defined in Pandas and we can bring it to Spark later.

```py
def get_month_and_year(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df.assign(month = df['DATE'].dt.month,
                     year = df['DATE'].dt.year)

get_month_and_year(df)
```

This gives us:

```
DATE    Value   month   year
2022-10-01  x   10  2022
2022-11-01  y   11  2022
2021-12-01  z   12  2021
2022-01-01  xy  1   2022
```

For the next operation, we will do a groupby-apply type operation where we group on the month, and check if we need to add a new row based on the current time. If we have to, then we perform the operation. Note that we will group the original DataFrame into each month before we perform the operation.

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

def generate_new_rows(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
    max_date = df['DATE'].max()
    next_date = max_date + relativedelta(years=1)
    if next_date <= datetime.now():
        # add new row
        new_row = {'DATE': [next_date], 'Value': [df.loc[df['DATE'].idxmax()]["Value"]],
                   'month': [next_date.month], 'year': [next_date.year]}
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(new_row)], ignore_index=True)
    return df

# test code
temp = get_month_and_year(df)
generate_new_rows(temp.loc[temp['month'] == 12])
```

which gives us:

```
DATE    Value   month   year
2021-12-01  z   12  2021
2022-12-01  z   12  2022
```

This looks like the expected output so now we can bring it to Spark with Fugue. We will use the `transform()` function which converts these to pandas_UDFs. Schema is required in PySpark so we need to supply it but Fugue provides a simpler interface.

```
import fugue.api as fa
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

# The only Fugue code
_tmp = fa.transform(sdf, get_month_and_year, schema="*, month:int, year:int")
out = fa.transform(_tmp, generate_new_rows, schema="*", partition={"by": "month"})

# It returns a Spark DataFrame
out.show()
```

The output:

```
+-------------------+-----+-----+----+
|               DATE|Value|month|year|
+-------------------+-----+-----+----+
|2021-12-01 00:00:00|    z|   12|2021|
|2022-12-01 00:00:00|    z|   12|2022|
|2022-10-01 00:00:00|    x|   10|2022|
|2022-01-01 00:00:00|   xy|    1|2022|
|2023-01-01 00:00:00|   xy|    1|2023|
|2022-11-01 00:00:00|    y|   11|2022|
+-------------------+-----+-----+----+
```

I am not fully sure but I also think this solution will be faster than the multiple loops. If you are performing this operation for multiple groups of data, just include the additional in the partition key.

Hope that helps!